# CSS Adding opacity to the background color of a div and not to the content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div with a simple background color and some text on the div. I want to decrease the opacity of the background color of this div but when I do that the opacity of the text on the div is also getting changed. Is there a way to change the opacity of the background color only?

```css
.main{
 background-color: red; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>Opacity of this text shouldn't be changed.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `background-color: rgba(rr, gg, bb, 0.5)`.

Comment: This question has already been asked [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884398/how-to-change-the-background-colours-opacity-in-css). Before posting a question on SO try to fix it by yourself first or at least search on Google for it. I'm downvoting this question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. I'll make sure that I do a proper research before asking a question next time. @MuhammadUsman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `alpha` channel of the color as below which is a 4th argument in `RGBA`

> rgba(255,0,0,0.1)    /* 10% opaque red */
>
>   rgba(255,0,0,0.4)    /* 40% opaque red */
>
>   rgba(255,0,0,0.7)    /* 70% opaque red */
>
>   rgba(255,0,0,  1)    /* full opaque red */

Note: `Red` will have `255` as first argument and others as `0` and you can change the 4th parameter from `0-1` for `opacity`

```css
.main{
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.7); 
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  /*opacity: 0.5;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>Opacity of this text shouldn't be changed.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Harish I updated your code, and you can execute it to see the effect.

Comment: @Harish `Red` is having `255` as first argument and others as `0` and you can change the 4th parameter from `0-1`

Answer (score 3):

Used RGBA color values are an extension of RGB color values with an alpha channel - which specifies the opacity for a color.

RGBA Stand for (red, green, blue, alpha)

```css
.main{
 background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5); 
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>Opacity of this text shouldn't be changed.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help  you :)

Answer (score 3):

```css
.main{
 background:rgba(220,0,0,0.2);
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>Opacity of this text shouldn't be changed.</p>
</div>
```

You can use CSS like this.

```
.main{
 background:rgba(170,0,0,0.2);
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```